# Basic android debugging

Tags: java, android, methods

I seem to get at force close when i start the app on my Nexsus 4. Big possibility its just me that fools around but i can't find anything wrong with the code.

Android Studio gives no erros. The reset method that is commented out i supposed to reset the checkbox and the TextView.

Why can't i define items before onCreate ? And when i define them after i cannot use them in the "reset" method..

Could someone plese have a look ?

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final TextView txtTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOut);
    final CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkTest);
    final Button btnTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    final EditText etTest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTest);
    String text = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            chkTest.setChecked(true);

            chkTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (chkTest.isChecked()) {
                                    txtTest.setText("Checked :)");
                            } else txtTest.setText("Not Checked");
                    }
            });

            btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                            //etTest.getText().toString(text);
                            text = etTest.toString();
                      // Reset(text);
                    }
            });
            /*void Reset(String text) {
                    chkTest.setChecked(false);
                    txtTest.setText(text);
            }*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }
}
```

This is the logcat error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{[...].MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: some logcat for the masses

Comment: See my answer below, homever it is better for you if you firstly improve your knowledge about java programming and also about android programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not initialize the item in this way! The layout is not inflated yet when is executed the code `final TextView txtTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOut);` so you have a null pointer exception. Also, define the reset() method outside the onCreate().
See the codes below:

```
    TextView txtTest = null;
    CheckBox chkTest = null;
    Button btnTest = null;
    EditText etTest = null;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOut);
    chkTest = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkTest);
    btnTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    etTest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTest);

    ....
 }


 void reset(String text) {
      chkTest.setChecked(false);
      txtTest.setText(text);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't find a view when is not created yet, try this:

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txtTest = null;
    CheckBox chkTest = null;
    Button btnTest = null;
    EditText etTest = null;
    String text = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            txtTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOut);
            chkTest = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkTest);
            btnTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
            etTest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTest);


            chkTest.setChecked(true);

            chkTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (chkTest.isChecked()) {
                                    txtTest.setText("Checked :)");
                            } else txtTest.setText("Not Checked");
                    }
            });

            btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                            //etTest.getText().toString(text);
                            text = etTest.toString();
                      // Reset(text);
                    }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }
    private void Reset(String text) {
            chkTest.setChecked(false);
            txtTest.setText(text);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks ! What you basicly do is set them up as null so that the reset code can reach them ?

Comment: you need to declare it at class level to see it in reset method (see I've changed scope of this method).  You need to set it to null, because at class declaration level, the view has not been inflated (created) yet, it gets created in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

You cant cause the items your are initializing is on the `activity_main.xml` and you set the content view after the initialization. Do the initialization in the `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must define the `Reset()` function outside the `onCreate()`. Thats not the correct way.
Secondly, I observe you have just started out this so I would suggest to define the `views` in the `xml` and then act upon them. You can set the `checkbox` true initially in the `xml` and the later set to false in the code.